# Current.Request.Url give my computer IP address not domain name

Tags: c#, iis

I don't know about networking, but I ask my sysadmin to host my application into subdomain at our official site, for example the official site of my office is *downtoearth.com*. And then he just ask IP address of my computer where I developed my application, then he said that my application already accessible from *myapp.downtoearth.com*

I can open my application from that domain, but my problem now is when I try to get my current URL, it give me IP address of my computer. I tried using  `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)` and `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host` but it give me the same result, what I want is my domain *myapp.downtoearth.com/* not my IP address. Is there some ways to solve it? 
My internet office use Proxy, so my computer didn't have an IP public. Of course if it give IP address of my computer, it will get error 404 not found. I use Razor MVC4 and IIS 8.

Sorry if there is some misspelling, English is not my default language and this is my first question at stackoverflow. I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "IP address of my computer"?

Comment: For example my computer IP address is 10.151.34.44 I don't know what sysadmin did, now my IIS web server at 10.151.34.44 can be accessed from _myapp.downtoearth.com_. but when I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host` it give me my IP address 10.151.34.44 not my domain _myapp.downtoearth.com_ that's what I mean by IP address of my computer. Of course I can't ping 10.151.34.44 from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your application is behind some load balancer. You shouldn't use the *Request.Url* as this is not working as it is expected in all circumstances. In your case the request is treated as local and this is why Url is your IP. Instead you can use *Request.UserHostName*. Please find [this link](http://rajeeshcv.com/2011/10/30/Stay-Away-from-Request-Url/)

Comment: I believe UserHostName refers to the host name of the *client* which is not usually what someone wants if they're trying to use Request.Url.